# Enabling browser cookies with Swagger-js

Tags: angularjs, http, cookies, swagger

I am using swagger-js/swagger-client (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js) in an AngularJs SPA to send REST request to a nodeJS server using the TryItOut Executor.

I am using PassportJS for authentication. When I use Angular's $http service with the withCredentials property set to true:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        withCredentials: true,
        url: 'http://someUrl/someRestPath/' })
```

, everything works OK - browser cookies are properly set, and every further request is successfully authenticated.

Switching to swagger-js Executor, I cannot get authenticated properly since cookies are not being set. I have tried the following:

```
var swaggerClient = new SwaggerClient(specUrl)
  .then(function (swaggerClient) {                                            
      swaggerClient.http.withCredentials = true; // this activates CORS, if necessary
```

as suggested in the documentation but this has no effect. Although I receive credentials when I authenticate with passport, further requests are unauthorized as cookies are not being set.

[Left: cookies not being sent; Right: cookies being set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iFrl.png)

How to enable this behavior using swagger-js?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution. The execute method of the Swagger-js client allows us to define our own http method. I simply used angular's $http service with the withCredentials set to true globally in the .config

```
import Swagger from 'swagger-client';
```

in .config:

```
angular.module('app', []).config(['$httpProvider',function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}
```

And then when you create your swagger client:

```
Swagger({ url: 'some swagger specification (yaml/json)' }).then(client => {
    client.execute({ http: $http, operationId: operationId, parameters: parameters});
```